# How to print fibonacci numbers in a flow service webmethods SoftwareAG Designer?

Tags: webmethod

How to print fibonacci numbers in a flow service webmethods SoftwareAG Designer?

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://wetransfer.com/downloads/eb18bd812b8a110e0b3da50b062e1d4920180109180701/82e916 for an IntegrationServer package with an example Flow-Service implementation.

Since Flow is not really suited for this kind of logic (it is quite verbose, see image below), try to use a standard Java Service instead.

[Screenshot of Flow-Service with Fibonacci service implemenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5IXR.png)